# Rails association works individually but not on includes/joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have a class `Tracker::Db::Service` with the following associations:

```
has_many :source_links, class_name: :Link, foreign_key: :source_key, conditions: [ 'state_id = 1 AND source_object_id = 3' ]
has_many :target_links, class_name: :Link, foreign_key: :target_key, conditions: [ 'state_id = 1 AND target_object_id = 3' ]
has_many :work_order_targets, through: :source_links, source: :work_order_as_target, class_name: :WorkOrder
has_many :work_order_sources, through: :target_links, source: :work_order_as_source, class_name: :WorkOrder
```

And then `Tracker::Db::Link` has these associations:

```
belongs_to :work_order_as_target, class_name: :WorkOrder, foreign_key: :target_key, conditions: [ 'target_object_id = 11' ]
belongs_to :work_order_as_source, class_name: :WorkOrder, foreign_key: :source_key, conditions: [ 'source_object_id = 11' ]
```

When I try to traverse these associations from an instance, such as: `service.work_order_targets`, it works perfectly.

However if I try to include/join these in a query I run into issues

```
Tracker::Db::Service.includes(:work_order_targets).limit(10)

Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'target_object_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `change_workorder`.* FROM `change_workorder`  WHERE `change_workorder`.`id` IN (4262, 4239, 4058, 4062, 4258, 4242, 4240, 4256, 4241, 4253) AND (( target_object_id = 11))
```

It is building the query incorrectly.
I have tried using the hash syntax for specifying conditions but this doesn't work either, it just becomes change_workorder.target_object_id.  It's doing this on both relationships `work_order_targets, work_order_sources`

`Tracker::Db::Service` has `id, name`

`Tracker::Db::Link` has `source_object_id, source_key, target_object_id, target_key`

`Tracker::Db::WorkOrder` has `id, name`

Unfortunately this is a 3rd parties application database ( open source project, OTRS + ITSM Module ), so I don't really have control over the structure, I'm just hooking our Rails app into it.

Comment: Have you tried the following `Tracker::Db::Service.includes(:target_links => :work_order_as_target).limit(10)` ?

Since your conditions are about columns of different table, you should precise them in your conditions string : `  conditions: ['services.state_id = 1 AND links.source_object_id = 3']`

with that, it is clearer that you need to join (or optionnally include ) :links in your query.

Pay attention of join and include, you need to join when you're conditioning on associated records and you need to include when you want to eager load. You should join AND include if you need both

Comment: Putting the table name in the conditions like that can cause issues on complex queries as the table gets aliased when it's joined, using the hash syntax for conditions fixes that.

Specifically joining through the source_links/target_links also doesn't fix it.  This is essentially what is happening on the has_many  :through associations anyway.

Comment: Oh yes I didn't thought of aliasing problems, my bad. My point xas that `Tracker::Db::Service.scoped` alone was the problem since it is conditioning on an outside table. Have you tried joining AND including :work_order_targets ? includes(:asscoaition) is not meant to allow querying of the association, just its eager loading

Comment: I'm actually not trying to query it, just trying to get the eager load. But both joining and/or including is throwing the exception.

Comment: But you are querying the links since your conditions are on columns of the "links" table. Can you try `Tracker::Db::Service.joins(:target_links).includes(:work_order_targets).limit(10)` ? .